# Is there a name for arrows of the type a -> a (in Haskell notation) in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

Whats the name of arrows in category theory that have this type:

```
a -> a
```

"From a type(?) to another object of the same type"

Or maybe there's no particular name for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These arrows are endomorphisms.